# In mat-table, edit the column header

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm using the angular material mat table in which I want to edit the column header name.
Suppose columns header list is Name, Age, Gender etc.
User wants to rename the header Name's Age to Date of birth then how is it possible.
which process I can follow for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can display columns header as input field, but this may cause a bad UX. I suggest to use an icon (button) or double click event to enable editing:

[image: edit-gif]

---

You can try:

**HTML:**

```
...
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <span
        *ngIf="!enableEditing"
        (dblclick)="enableEditing = true"
        style="cursor: pointer"
      >
        {{value | titlecase}}
      </span>
      <input
        *ngIf="enableEditing"
        type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="value"
        (keydown.enter)="editName()"
        (focusout)="editName()"
      />
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
...
```

And `editName()` to save change:

```
editName() {
  this.displayedColumns = ['position', this.value, 'weight', 'symbol'];
  this.enableEditing = false;
}
```

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/edit-header)**